# Count the amount of Cases and set Status on CaseStatus table if every counted amount is the statusCode 601 in the Cursor

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Hello I made a cursor that check every row and check the status of the Caseinventory and then sets the status on the caseStatus. Problem is if I set the last counted row to 601 and it changes the code to 3 (shown in the code) it will not check if the rest is 601 and then just set the status to 3 even though rest is 600 or 599.
How can I solve this? should I count the amount on the CaseInventory and then check the status on every counted row and then update if the value is 601? and how do you do this? first time using cursor.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetsStatusOnCaseStatusByCaseInventoryStatus]
    @StatusID INT,
    @ID int,
    @CaseInventoryID int
AS
BEGIN
--find caseID on CaseInventoryID
declare @CaseID int = (SELECT CaseID from [dbo].[factCaseInventory] where ID=@ID)

--CaseStatus
declare @CaseIkkeStartet int =1
declare @CaseIgangStatus int = 2
declare @CaseDoneStatus int = 3

--CaseInventoryStatus
DECLARE @NotStarted int = 599
DECLARE @Nocode int = 600
declare @YesCode int = 601

--Cursor
declare CaseInventoryCursor cursor for 
Select ID, StatusID, CaseID from [dbo].[factCaseInventory] 

open CaseInventoryCursor

fetch next from CaseInventoryCursor into @ID, @StatusID, @CaseID

while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin 

SELECT @StatusID =StatusID from [dbo].[factCaseInventory] where CaseID=@CaseID

if(@StatusID = @Nocode)
begin 
update [dbo].[factCase] set CaseStatusID=@CaseDoneStatus where CaseId=@CaseID
end

else if (@StatusID =@YesCode)
begin
update [dbo].[factCase] set CaseStatusID=@CaseIgangStatus where CaseId=@CaseID
end

else if (@StatusID =@NotStarted)
begin
update [dbo].[factCase] set CaseStatusID=@CaseIkkeStartet where CaseId=@CaseID
end

fetch next from CaseInventoryCursor into @ID, @StatusID, @CaseID

end
close CaseInventoryCursor
deallocate CaseInventoryCursor

END
```

Comment: Why would you need to loop here? This is a simple `update` query, no need for RBAR.

Comment: I have multiple rows I want to check if status is either 600 or 601 and based if they all have the status 601 I want to set another status to 3 or 2 if they are not all status 601 
how else would I check every single values in the rows?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: im using my sql

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me why you're passing parameters to your stored procedure when you then either don't use them, or overwrite them with new values before you use them.

However, if what you're trying to do is update each `factCase` record with a new `CaseStatusID` value based upon the related `factCaseInventory` record's `StatusID` value, you can just do a simple `UPDATE` with a join:

```
update fc set CaseStatusID = 
                case fci.StatusID
                    when 600 then 3
                    when 601 then 2
                    when 599 then 1
                end
from factCaseInventory fci
left join factCase fc on fvi.CaseID = fc.CaseID
```